# Programmatically binding ComboBox ItemSource and Selected Value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In the code below i am attempting to bind the ItemsSource and SelectedValue of a combobox to two different properties on my model.  TickerList is a Dictionary[string, string>.  The list shows up fine and when i make a selection, SelectedValue is correctly populated.  However, when i SET ViewModel.SelectedTicker property to one of the values of the dictionary, the selected item in the ComboBox does not change.  I was under the impression with this type of binding, if i set the value on the model, the control will reflect that change.  Any thoughts on what i may be doing wrong?  (note: i am intentionally displaying the dictionary key and using the value of the dictionary as the selectedValePath, this is also the value that i set on the viewmodel.SelectedTicker property..that is by design).

```
        //bind to list of TickerList
        Binding listBinding = new Binding() { Source = ViewModel.TickerList };
        cbPriceSource.DisplayMemberPath = "Key";
        cbPriceSource.SelectedValuePath = "Value";
        cbPriceSource.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, listBinding);

        //bind selection to ViewModel.SelectedTicker
        cbPriceSource.DataContext = ViewModel;
        Binding selectedItemBinding = new Binding() { Source = ViewModel, Path = new PropertyPath("SelectedTicker"), Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
        cbPriceSource.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty, selectedItemBinding);
```

Comment: Does your setter for SelectedTicker trigger a PropertyChanged event?

Comment: That was the problem.  i implemented INotifyPropertyChanged and all is well.  thanks